# Play a specific mission over in Mass Effect 3

Tags: mass-effect-3, pc

So I'm playing through mass effect 3 and I need to go back and get reference shots from certain levels.

I was too used to steam and got this on on origins so all my screen shots didn't take. I need them for reference material for a project.

Specifically the comm tower on palaven. I now have a screen cap system in place but that mission takes a bit to get to so I don't want to run through the intro of the game again just to get there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a tool to edit your save (you create a game, save and quit) to modify everything, even you actual progress, and select the mission you want.

You can try with **Gibbed Mass Effect 3 Save Editor**, which is the most popular an easy-to-use editor. Here how to use it: [http://benchmark3d.com/mass-effect-3-save-game-editor](https://web.archive.org/web/20140331183130/http://benchmark3d.com/mass-effect-3-save-game-editor)

Here you have the mission code (from [this source](http://www.cheathappens.com/show_board2.asp?headID=111536&titleID=17475)):

> 59915  Priority: Palaven

You can use this code under the **Plot** Mass Effect 3 tab, and **Missions** sub tab.

Comment: @kotekzot I was searching for a good tutorial

Comment: Still doesn't explain how to actually load a particular mission.